# The convolutional neural network i'm trying to train is settling at a particular range of loss value, how should i avoid it?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Description: I am trying to train an alexnet similar(actually same but without groups) CNN from scratch (50000 images, 1000 classes and x10 augmentation). Each epoch has 50,000 iterations and image size is 227x227x3.

There was a smooth cost decline and improvement in the accuracy for a few initial epochs but now i'm facing this problem where the cost has settled to ~6(started from 13) for a long time, its been a day and cost is continuously oscillating in the range 6.02-6.7. The accuracy has also become stagnant.

Now i'm not sure what to do and not having any proper guidance. Is this the problem of vanishing gradients in local minima? So, to avoid this should i decrease my learning rate? Currently the learning rate is 0.08 with Relu activation (which helps in avoiding vanishing gradients), Glorot initialization and a batch size of 96. Before making another change and again training for days, i want to make sure that i'm moving in a correct direction. What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: May be you have reached the accuracy which is the best for your data? How big is the classification error?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, shouldn't the cost be close to 0(? or ~1atleast), if the training goes the best. Should i try a bigger network? The validation error reduced from 6 to 4 and became stagnant. Accuracy right now is about 20%

Comment: The cost function does not have to become 0, it has to reach its minima. Your images are in RGB format, aren't they? If so, may be try to use gray scaled versions to gain first results for debuging? What is the current net structure?

Comment: the current net is similar to alexnet and the input image is RGB (227x227x3). Isn't there a possibility of it getting stuck in the local minima? or how do i decide that the cost is the best for the training data?

Comment: To answer this question you can try to initialize the weights with some other data. Where can I find the alexnet project with data samples and so on? I would like to implement it as well. I visited the web page but did not find the data set